# insert php mysql query in hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql, post, hyperlink, get

I want to se output my products classified with category that they belong to it. I mean, when I click on the TV just TVs are output in category.php. I have this code for it, but it doesnt give any result.

Here my codes

**index.php**

```
<a href="category.php?id='.$category['TV'].'"><span>TVs</span></a>
<a href="category.php?id='.$category['mp3'].'"><span>mp3-players</span></a>
<a href="category.php?id='.$category['laptop'].'"><span>Laptops</span></a>
```

**category.php**

```
$category=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='$category'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<? echo $rows['name'].$rows['description'].$rows['price']; ?>
```

Comment: That is an extremely unsafe SQL call, that can easily be SQL Injected.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: My suggestion is you take a look at, and start to use `PDO`, and also spend some time reading about security, specifically here at SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
<a href="category.php?id='.$category['TV'].'"><span>TVs</span></a>
<a href="category.php?id='.$category['mp3'].'"><span>mp3-players</span></a>
<a href="category.php?id='.$category['laptop'].'"><span>Laptops</span></a>
```

It should be:

```
<a href="category.php?id=TV"><span>TVs</span></a>
<a href="category.php?id=mp3"><span>mp3-players</span></a>
<a href="category.php?id=laptop"><span>Laptops</span></a>
```

Then you can get the value like this:

```
$category = $_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='".$category."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

---

Side note: aside from using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, please avoid using unsanitize query string/input and use `PDO::` or `mysqli_*` instead.